# A puzzle from OPUS VIII

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

I just got a mail from an online puzzler who calls himself OPUS VIII. He said he wants to see if I have what it takes to become a member of his secret online puzzle club. He said it's time limited and that he'll send a mail when the time is up. I have no idea who he is or how he got my email, maybe from a friend of a friend who knows I like puzzles.

Well, anyways... here's the puzzle he sent.

---

*"Damn, those basketball players are really ....."*

*".....! I don't want it"*

*"School is so boring, always end up .....dreaming whenever we have class."*

*"Well it's too late now, the store is ....."*

*"Come on, try to have some ..... thinking man, it'll be fine."*

*"You know, back in the good ..... days this would never happen."*

*"No ..... no cry, was a great song"*

*"Their defence is not that good, it's definitely their ..... link."*

**Tell me the answer. You only have one try so remember to give me the correct one ;)**

---

Quick! What answer should I send to him in order to become a member of the club?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> **antonyms**.

First ...

> ... fill in the blanks. This is straightforward:
>
>  "Damn, those basketball players are really **tall**"
>  "**No**! I don't want it"
>  "School is so boring, always end up **day**dreaming whenever we have class."
>  "Well it's too late now, the store is **closed**"
>  "Come on, try to have some **positive** thinking man, it'll be fine."
>  "You know, back in the good **old** days this would never happen."
>  "No **woman** no cry, was a great song"
>  "Their defence is not that good, it's definitely their **weak** link."

Then ...

> ... find antonyms, words that mean the opposite of each word:
>
>  tall — **short**
>  no — **yes**
>  day — **night**
>  closed — **open**
>  positive — **negative**
>  old — **young**
>  woman — **man**
>  weak — **strong**
>
>  Their first letters spell **synonyms** – so going with the theme, the answer should be its antonym, *viz* **antonyms**?

A hint is given ...

> ... by the mysterious puzzlers name, **Opus VIII**, which sounds (a bit) like "opposite".

Comment: Well done! But rot13(gur nafjre fubhyq or gur nagbalz bs flabalzf juvpu vf nagbalzf vgfrys.. gel gb frr ubj gur gvgyr (uvf anzr) vf pbaarpgrq gb gur svany nafjre. Gung jnf n pyhr.)

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but decided against it. I think I see now what the mysterious name means. (I first thought it might be an anagram.)

Comment: Looks good now. Gotta say it really fast to make it work though :D Tick is yours!